# Accessing nested child components in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Using v2.2.2. I have the following structure in my VueJS app. How can I access all of the Account components from a method on my Post component? The number of Accounts is dynamic - I want to grab all of the loaded `Account` components and iterate over them.

I know it's got something to do with `$refs` and `$children`, I just can't seem to figure out the right path.

```vue
<Root>
    <Post>
        <AccountSelector>
            <Account ref="anAccount"></Account>
            <Account ref="anAccount"></Account>
            <Account ref="anAccount"></Account>
        </AccountSelector>
    </Post>
</Root>
```

Comment: The whole refs thing is extremely fragile if components are deeply nested and/or they get moved around during development.  Check this way out instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47889841/34806

Answer (score 59, accepted):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs

> Despite the existence of props and events, sometimes you might still need to directly access a child component in JavaScript. To achieve this you have to assign a reference ID to the child component using ref. For example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <user-profile ref="profile"></user-profile>
</div>

var parent = new Vue({ el: '#parent' })
// access child component instance
var child = parent.$refs.profile
```

> When ref is used together with v-for, the ref you get will be an array
> or an object containing the child components mirroring the data
> source.

Basically inside `AccountSelector.vue` you can do `this.$refs.anAccount.map(account => doThingToAccount(account))`

**Edit**
The above answer is for accessing a direct child.

Currently there is no way to access a non direct parent / child component with `$refs`. The best way to get access to their data would be through events https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication or by using [Vuex](http://vuex.vuejs.org/) (Which i would recommend).

Non direct parent - child communication is very tricky without 1 of these 2 methods.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I bubble up that data to `Post`? I'm looking to access the data inside of Post, one level above AccountSelector. If I do `post.$refs.anAccount` I get undefined. I'm missing a level.

Comment: Sorry i get you now, i'm not sure if you can get undirect children. The best way to get access to their data would be through events http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication or by using Vuex (Which i would recommend). Non direct parent - child communication is very tricky without 1 of these 2 methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reference - that paragraph does indeed state that I'll need to use Vuex. I'm actually currently doing that, just thought there was a more direct way! Can you modify your answer so I can accept it as the answer?

Comment: I've updated the answer to more directly match the question asked

Comment: I'm very late to the party, but would an **event bus** not be your best option here?

Answer (score 12):

You can access nested components data using $refs and if you want to access the refs inside of it you first have to target the first element of the first refs ([0])

example: `parent.$refs[0].$refs.anAccount`